# elasticsearch: apostrophe as word delimiter, with exceptions

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a multilingual environment and are having trouble matching when apostrophes are involved.

1. We want a search for "can't" to match "can't".
2. We want a search for "all'acqua" in quotes to match "all'acqua".
3. But we also want a search for "acqua" to match "all'acqua".

How can we get this done?
Currently, we are using an elision filter with a list of articles. That works somewhat but a search for "all'acqua" in quotes fails.

I tried a "word_delimiter" filter with a list of protected words (can't, won't, etc.) but that didn't work.

How can we get it working?

Comment: OK, maybe that is too much to ask...

Let's simplify it: how can I make the apostrophe  == whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the [combo analyzer](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-analysis-combo/).
As only one tokenizer is allowed per analyzer , this feature is not directly possible.
But if you can put a white space tokenizer in one analyzer and standard tokenizer in another analyzer , that should do the trick.